# how i can set or change the default date in jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

in a dynamic form when content come from server through ajax request i want to create a new datepicker based on existing textbox who already intialize when page load.

actually ajax request return data and i show the form with fillling the default data.

```
 $("#llogin").datepicker({ disabled: true });
    $("#flogin").datepicker({ disabled: true });
```

this code i run on document ready and later i change them through

```
   $("#llogin").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", ParseJSONDate(fdate));
        $("#flogin").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", ParseJSONDate(ldate));
```

now i see that two date who i not want. i want to set the date who come from ajax request.

how i can set the default date without setting a another date. i just want to change the date from the date who i got from ajax request.

can someone show me code to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use its defaultDate property. Just set it to a JavaScript date object with the date you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="llogin" name="llogin"/>
```

and

```
$("#llogin").datepicker({ disabled: false});

var myDate = new Date();
var prettyDate =(myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' +
        myDate.getFullYear();
$("#llogin").val(prettyDate);
```

In above code I am assigning the current date to the datepicker... Instead of that you can assign your json returned date...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using jquery's default date in the datepicker:

```
var fromDate = new Date('5-6-2015');

jQuery(".divFromDate").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date('1/1/2000'),
    maxDate: '-8',
    defaultDate: fromDate,
    ...
```